# How to flush token to another contract from token holder's token balance from ERC-20 contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, erc-20, contract-deployment

I have to implement the following scenario:
- One ERC-20 token contract.
- Another contract which will flush tokens of ERC-20 tokens.
- Add these tokens to one, defined Admin address.

Note: All procedure without using forwarder address.

[image]

Comment: Did I undestand correctly that you want to send all tokens from one wallet to a contract address? The wallet owner has to either send the tokens directly or approve a transfer with the `approve` function - nobody can "flush" the tokens without approval or direct transfer.

Comment: Yes. very close. Okay lets say I have one ERC20 token contract which has 10 holders containing individuals amount, Now I want another contract, using this contract I can retrieve and get token holder's balance at some predefined user address.

Comment: I've edited my question with pictorial representation. hope it'll be useful.